# How to modify this SQLiteOpenHelper insert operation so it becomes a ContentResolver operation (with transactions)

Tags: android

I have this SQLiteOpenHelper operation that I need to become a ContentResolver operation so I can do this even if the application is destroyed

```
    sqliteOpenHelper.database.beginTransaction();
    try {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("userId", userId);
            values.put("userName", userName);
            values.put("userEmail", userEmail);

            sqliteOpenHelper.database.insert("users", null, values);
            sqliteOpenHelper.database.setTransactionSuccessful();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            sqliteOpenHelper.database.endTransaction();
        }
```

Normally I know how to query the database with a ContentResolver, like so:

```
                Uri contentUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContentProviderDB.CONTENT_URI, "users");
                String selection = "user_id = " + String.valueOf(userId);
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, selection, null, null);
```

**But in the INSERT above there are transactions so that is what I dont know how to deal with.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [***contentResolver.insert (uri, contentValues)***](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#insert(android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues)).

---

Instead of:

```
sqliteOpenHelper.database.beginTransaction();
try {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("userId", userId);
    values.put("userName", userName);
    values.put("userEmail", userEmail);

    sqliteOpenHelper.database.insert("users", null, values);
    sqliteOpenHelper.database.setTransactionSuccessful();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();

} finally {
    sqliteOpenHelper.database.endTransaction();
}
```

you need to write:

```
try {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("userId", userId);
    values.put("userName", userName);
    values.put("userEmail", userEmail);
    Uri uri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(contentUri, values);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: And how about the transactions? Later on in the same class I have to do a new insert

Comment: Also, what do I do with this uri?

Comment: This is the Uri of new inserted row. So you can log it.

Comment: So transactions are automatically handled?

Comment: Yes. No worry about that